# Формирование подписи checksum

Tags: python, django

Всем привет! Есть форма:

1) Вводим поля

2) Нажимаем кнопку отправить формируется подпись на сервере и отправляются данные к https://test.test/pay

Вопрос как подставить в checksum подпись основываясь на введенных данных и тогда  отправлять к https://test.test/pay

```
<form method="POST"
action="https://test.test/pay">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
<input type="hidden" name="description" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="checksum" value="8cbaf6e9d0f91aad132773a7ef470e119681cfca">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Перед отправкой формы заюзать Ajax, не?

Comment: checksum = hmac.new(key='123',msg='amount=10;description=test;merchant_order_id=123',digestmod=hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()

Подпись уже есть, как-то же можно сделать на django и вставить checksum

Answer (score 1):

Я ж и говорю:

1. делаете вьюху для получению подписи
2. перехватываете событие onsubmit
3. сереализуете данные формы
4. делаете запрос к вьюхе, которая выдает подписи
5. полученный результат вставляете в форму
6. делаете сабмит формы (уже с воткнутым туда hidden checksum)
7. ...
8. PROFIT!

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю суть действа — принять форму, сделать платеж, подписать, отправить дальше мерчанту — возможно, все должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
# <form action="http://your.example.org/handle-payment" method="POST">
#    {% csrf_token %}
#    <input name="amount" type="text" value="">
#    <input name="description" type="text" value="">
#    <input type="submit">
# </form>

# Ключ подписи храним не посреди кода вьюшки, а в settings.py, добавив туда
# MERCHANT_SIGNING_KEY = "..."

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@require_POST
@transaction.commit_manually
def handle_payment(request):
    # Разбираем данные формы, проверяем. Фильтруем поля —
    # вдруг злой хакер или излишне напичканный расширениями
    # браузер добавит отсебятины.
    post_data = {}
    for key in ("amount", "description"):
        if not key in request.POST:
            # Ругаемся, завершаем обработку
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("BUG REF#1234: Missing required data.")
        post_data[key] = str(request.POST[key])

    try:
        # Создаем платеж, дополняем форму его ID
        # (при отправке формы мы же не знаем ID, так?)
        payment = Payment(**post_data)
        payment.save()
        post_data["merchant_order_id"] = str(payment.id)

        # Подписываем данные формы
        post_data["checksum"] = hmac.new(
            key=settings.MERCHANT_SIGNING_KEY,
            msg=";".join("%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in post_data.iteritems()),
            digestmod=hashlib.sha1
        ).hexdigest()

        # Отправляем (с сервера) итоговый подписанный запрос на мерчанта
        merchant_req = requests.post("http://merchant.example.net/pay",
            # auth=(settings.MERCHANT_USER, settings.MERCHANT_PASSWORD),
            data=post_data
        )

        # Проверяем ответ, например, просто посмотрев код
        if merchant_req.status_code != 200:
            # Не прошло, откатываем транзакцию, пишем логи
            transaction.rollback()
            logger.error("Merchant rejected payment request [...]") # TODO: Лог!
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("BUG REF#4321: Merchant rejected")
    except Exception, e:
        logger.error("Exception during payment processing [...]")
        raise e # Перебрасываем исключение дальше, пусть middleware разбирается
    else:
        transaction.commit()

    logger.notice("Successfully processed payment #%d: [...]", payment.id)
    # Заканчиваем редиректом, чтобы POST не повторился
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("payment_handled", payment.id))
```

Это то, что надо, или я неправильно понял суть?

Comment: То что нужно, немного есть моменты не понятные. Эта интеграция подходит для процессинга с полным API. Если использовать SimpleAPI тогда нужно отправить(подписать и т.д.) из браузера и в ответ приедет форма процессингово центра для заполнение карты и т.д.

Comment: То что нужно, всё работает! Какой раз выручаешь!!!